# Unix pattern match script is not matching against the column pattern

Tags: linux, unix

I am facing an issue with the pattern matching in unix . I was trying to validate the string " VIN1234@56789111a" against the pattern [A-Z0-9]{17}. result should be this validation needs to be failed {as it has lower case and special characters} , but in the script the validation passed.

```
col_patt=[A-Z0-9]{17} sep=, input=filename n=1{column position in file name } 
 val=$(awk -F "$sep" -v n="$col_pos" -v m="$col_patt" -v d="$input" 
              '$n !~ "^" m "$" 
              { printf "%s:%s:%s\n", d, FNR, 
                $n > "/dev/stderr" count++ }
                END {print count+0}' "$cp_input" 2>> $script_path/errors_${file_id}.log )
```

Comment: Please put that code snippet into your question, not in the comments.

Comment: i tried for past two days . but don't understand why its throwing error and not allowing me to submit the questions

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77137761/edit), don't replay with another answer.

Comment: true . My the string match i am trying to do is should fail based on the pattern [A-Z0-9]{17} . But it is not failing for {VIN1234@56789111a}

Comment: Oops! I should have read your Q more carefully. SOrry! BUT ... on my system `echo 'VIN1234@56789111a' | awk '{if ($0 ~ /^[A-Z0-9]{17}$/){print "OK" ; exit 0}else{print "Fail" ;exit 1}}'` prroduces `Fail`. Does you file have `\r\n` line endings? Check with `cat -vet file | head -1` if you see `^M$` at the end of the line, then `dos2unix file`. Would still prefer to read the awk code not on one lilne (-;! Good luck.

Comment: Tnx for formatting your code. I notice some issues (still (-;). Did you check your code at https://shellcheck.net? Do you really have `sep= ,` and `n= 1`? The assignment can't happen with the space after `=`. I would expect error messages. Is your `$input` the `VIN1234@56789111a` string? I recommend make a 1 line test file with your problem data, eliminate all extra code and get just the match to fail (as required), then add your nice-to-have's of  `-v m=`, `$n`, etc. Also, I think you need a semi-colon before `count++`. Good luck.

Comment: i have tried the below code : awk -F "," '$1 ~ "^[A-Z0-9]{17}$" { printf "%s:%s:%s\n", "test_file.txt", FNR, $1 > "/dev/stderr"; count++ } END {print count+0}'   but it never given a results looks like it is going into infinite loops . i checked the file it has only one line and no blank lines

Comment: awk -F "," '$1 !~ "^[A-Z0-9]{17}$" { printf "%s:%s:%s\n", "test_file.txt", FNR, $1 > "/dev/stderr" count++ } END {print count+0}' "test_file.txt" 2 >> error_log_anjali.log
it thrown an error                   awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=test_file.txt FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `/dev/stderr0' (Permission denied)

Comment: Good info above here. I have to walk the dog but will write up something when I get back.

Comment: You're very close (I think). Try `awk -F "," '$1 ~ "^[A-Z0-9]{17}$" { printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $1 > "/dev/stderr"; count++ } END {print count+0}'  test_file.txt` . If that doesn't work, please update your question with an **Edit** section at the bottom where you include the above code (any flagged syntax erors fixed), AND the contents of your `test_file.txt` file. As you've spent so much time on this already, take 2-3 hrs and work your way thru [Grymoire's Awk Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Comment: I make a `test_file.txt` with containing 2 lines, `VIN1234@56789111a
VIN12345567891111` . Guess which line you code prints out? You're missing one thing to flag records that **don't** match your regexp. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much , awk -F ","  -v n="1" -v d="test_file.txt"  -v m="[A-Z0-9]{17}" '$n !~ "^" m "$" {printf "%s:%s:%s\n", d, FNR, $n > "/dev/stderr"; count++ }END {print count+0}' "test_file.txt" 2>> errors_1.log    Thsi script worked as expected . But when i tried to replace the variable teh same issue popped up . will try tomorrow and see .Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but for any further issues on this, please (as mentioned above) update the body of your question with an **Edit** section or post a new question. It is OK to leave a msg like "See Edit in my question". Good luck.

Comment: And especially when doing text processing sample input data is indispensable, as is the actual code, not some pseudo-code ...

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

```
if echo 'VIN1234@56789111a' | grep -q '^[A-Z0-9]{17}$'; then
    echo SUCCESS
else
    echo FAILED
fi
```

or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
if [[ VIN1234@56789111a =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{17}$ ]]; then
    echo SUCCESS
else
    echo FAILED
fi
```

or using `awk`:

```
echo VIN1234@56789111a |
    awk '{if (/^[A-Z0-9]{17}$/) print "SUCCESS"; else print "FAILED"}'
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles , I would need a help in review the awk statement , as i am using a bunch of files

Comment: This is imaginary `awk/shell` code. Can't help here. But added `awk` way.